# If we want use S3 to host Python packages, how can we tell pip where to find the newest version?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pip

we are trying to come up with a solution to have AWS S3 to host and distribute our Python packages.

Basically what we want to do is using `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` to create a wheel. Upload it to S3. Then any server or any machine can do `pip install $http://path/on/s3`. (including a virtualenv in AWS lambda)
(We've looked into Pypicloud and thought it's an overkill.)

Creating package and installing from S3 work fine. There is only one issue here: we will release new code and give them different versions. If we host our code on Pypi, you can upgrade some packages to their newest version by calling `pip install package --upgrade`.

But if you host your packages on S3, how do you let pip know there's a newer version exists? How do you roll back to an older version by simply giving pip the version number? Is there a way to let pip know where to look for different version of wheels on S3?

Comment: You'll want to have a look at the [Hosting your Own Simple Repository](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/self_hosted_repository/) documentation in the Python Packaging User Guide and [`pip`'s `--index-url` / `--extra-index-url`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#cmdoption-i) parameters.

Comment: Is it really overkill if you wouldn't have to figure this stuff out? What are you really gaining by not using the software someone already built to do what you want to do? One less server or service to manage? Unless you have no servers currently and want to keep it that way (which sounds unrealistic these days) or your package uploading/downloading would be a huge load, I don't see why that matters. Just using it would probably be less time investment than trying to roll your own.

Comment: @jpmc26 Right now we only have 1 package we want to distribute this way. Plus Pypicloud doesn't seem to support Python 3 yet. All our code are in Python 3.

Comment: @FZhu If the server runs under Python 2, this has zero effect on your ability to run Python 3 code anywhere... The install instructions even tell you to use virtualenv. *Worst* case you need a server that doesn't run anything but Python 2 and pypicloud; you can use other servers for everything else. The only thing that impacts your ability to use Python 3 is compatibility with local `pip`, which I'm pretty sure is not a problem. As for one package, that doesn't affect the time you spend (time = $$) solving this problem, and if this is a success, you'll probably have more packages later.

Comment: I think I see where you're getting the Python 3 compatibility concern: https://github.com/mathcamp/pypicloud/issues/21. But this is the pypicloud code itself; it doesn't affect your packages.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thank you, what concerns me is building compatibility. I actually just tried out with virtualenv, uploading and downloading works fine. But the package wasn't built properly. When I install, it raise error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'some/path/to/requirements.txt'. When built with Python 3 it doesn't have such issue. I'm new to Python, does this look like a compatibility issue to you?

Comment: Actually, doing "python3 setup.py sdist upload -r pypicloud" raises the same error too. So it's probably not Pypicloud's compatibility issue. But it's another problem. I'll try to figure out myself. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: As far as I understand, you should only be sending already assembled packages to PyPI. It doesn't build them for you. It's your `setup.py` script that uses setuptools to assembles the packages, and if it's a source distribution instead of a wheel, pip calls out to do the appropriate building at install time. Unless you have native dependencies, it's better to use wheels than source distributions, though. PyPI just provides a protocol/structure for discovery of packages and their versions.

Comment: @jpmc26 I see what's going on. I used "python3 setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r pypicloud" from pypicloud doc to build a source distribution. What I really should do is "python3 setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r pypicloud" to build a wheel file then upload. And it works.

Comment: Well, to clarify a bit, it's always better to use wheels when you can, but if you have native dependencies, you need a source distribution for Linux, since that typically needs to be compiled at install time to ensure the dependencies work out correctly. For Mac and Windows, though, you want wheels for everything. (...I think you mean `python3 setup.py sdist upload -r pypicloud` to build a source distribution. ;) Glad to hear you got it!)

Comment: @jpmc26 (We probably should move this to chat but I don't have enough reputation, oh well) Why Mac can't compile and ensure dependencies work at install time?

Comment: @jpmc26 Right, that's what I meant. You helped solving a big problem for us. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It's really more a question of why source distros for Linux. All the systems can build from source, but it's annoying. Linux (and BSD would have to use it as well) is usually given a source distribution because there are *so many* Linux distros that supporting them all would be ludicrous. Several of the bigger Linux distros (flavors of Debian & Red Hat especially) compile a lot of Python packages with native dependencies and include them in the OS package manager so you don't have to build them. That was happening before wheels, so there isn't much pressure for wheel to support Linux directly.

Comment: Updated link for @LukasGraf comment : [Hosting your own Simple Repository](https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/)

Comment: AWS now offers a dedicated repository-service called [AWS CodeArtifact](https://aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/) which also supports `pip`.

Answer (score 32):

AWS S3 can be used as a pypi server with minimal configuration and no other additional dependencies.

Suppose you want to use the bucket `mypackages` for hosting your private packages - `awesomepy` and `rattlesnake`.

After you have created the bucket in S3, go to its properties, click on **Static website hosting** card and enable the option **Use this bucket to host a website**. Note down the *Endpoint* mentioned above the radio button.

Below is how you have to arrange the folders and files ([docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/)):

```
mypackages
    |
    |---awesomepy
    |       |---awesomepy-1.10.0-py27-none-any.whl 
    |       |---awesomepy-1.10.3-py27-none-any.whl 
    |       |---index.html
    |
    |---rattlepy
            |---rattlesnake-0.1.1-py27-none-any.whl 
            |---index.html
```

The `index.html` files in the package folders will have content like below

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Links</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Links</h1>
    <a href='awesomepy-1.10.0-py27-none-any.whl'>awesomepy-1.10.0-py27-none-any.whl </a>
    <br />
    <a href='awesomepy-1.10.3-py27-none-any.whl'>awesomepy-1.10.3-py27-none-any.whl </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Wheel packages have to follow proper naming convention. Refer to [PEP 427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention) for details. For the dummy package - `awesomepy-1.10.3-py27-none-any.whl`, we are assuming,

1. Language implementation is Python 2.7 - `py27`
2. ABI tag is none - `none`
3. Platform is any - `any`

Finally you can install the packages using the below command. Ensure your packages have different names than that of pypi packages. Prefixing the package name with your company initials is one simple solution.

```
pip install awesomepy rattlesnake==0.1.1 --extra-index-url=<s3 Endpoint> --trusted-host=<s3 Endpoint without http>
```

**Upgrading packages using `pip install awesomepy --upgrade` will also work with this approach.**

Also, modify your bucket permissions to restrict the packages to intended clients. One way to do this is:
Select **Permissions** tab in the bucket --> Edit [**Bucket Policy**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

*Original Credit: My ex-manager, Adlon :)*

Comment: Where should I place my setup.py in packaging phase? inside each library folder or outside ?

Comment: `setup.py` is part of your `.whl` package.

Comment: I mean, to obtain a structure like the one you showed, how should I build my library? should I plave the setup.py in each subfolder?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question(s) correctly. This answer is not about how to create a pip package(whl or any other archive format) by packaging a setup.py and the actual code. It's about how to arrange those packages in S3 for installing them through pip. Placing setup.py (and code) in directories will not work.

Comment: The questioning is exactly on how to create the wheel package. To obtain each package how can o do it locally on my PC?

Comment: I had already followed it, however if you want to create a structure like the one in the S3, putting the setup.py in the root, would create a single wheel package with all the submodules, which is not the desired result, because in the S3 we want a package per module. Am I correct?

Comment: `.whl` is an archive. It `contains` your setup.py file. Your will place the `.whl` files in the subfolders. Each whl file represents one specific python package. Why would you put setup.py in the root? What do you mean by '...a package per module'?

Comment: The guide you posted, which is the same I followed puts the setup in the root folder of your package. Let's suppose I had multiple subpackages(sorry for my previous mistake) made up of modules, where should I put my setup.py?

Comment: I have nowhere mentioned `setup.py` in my answer.

Comment: The website you posted 5 comments above is a python guide

Comment: @3nomis I think you're better off asking your own top-level question on StackOverflow. This one is about hosting packages, not about making packages. I think you have some confusion between the term package and module. A package contains modules. A package has a setup.py.  A package repository hosts packages. I'm not sure what you mean by subpackage. In a top-level question you can explain better and get more appropriate answers than here.

Comment: In terms of this answer, I'm not sure it's possible with S3 to use static website hosting and give it a bucket policy that requires authentication (or how you would even do that with pip without signing the request in some way). You might be able to hack it based on SourceIP in some way, but that doesn't seem very flexible.

Comment: Yes, authentication is not possible. In our case, we used CIDR IPs in the bucket policy to restrict access to the intended VPCs.

Comment: is there a tool that creates the directories and add all the index.html files?

Comment: @DanielDelgado - I created http://pypi.org/project/s3-pypi-proxy which dynamically generates the PyPI index, and supports authentication AWS credentials. Using this, you start the proxy locally and run `pip install --extra-index-url=http://localhost:5000/some-s3-bucket/simple secret-package`

Answer (score 3):

Shameless plug: I had the exact same problem, and wasn't happy with any of the existing solutions, so I wrote a small Lmabda/Terraform combo that does the trick: https://github.com/berislavlopac/plambdapi

Hope it helps!