# How to host a private python package manager in Azure or AWS

Tags: python, azure, amazon-web-services, pypi, pypiserver

I work in a small team of Python developers and we aim to create a private package manager to store our packages. I came cross [pypicloud](https://pypi.stevearc.com/#/) and following its [tutorial](http://pypicloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/getting_started.html) I've successfully been able to upload and install packages stored in AWS-S3. That's fantastic.

However, the private package manager is launched and hosted locally typing `pserve server.ini` in the terminal. The package manager is then accessible at `http://0.0.0.0:6543/#/`. Ideally, I want this server to be:

- hosted in the cloud (possibly Azure but AWS is fine)
- up and running 24/7
- secure. Users must authenticate in order to see the package manager and the packages.
- not hosted in a operative system but something higher level (e.g. docker container or Azure function app?) since it would be much easier to maintain, geo-replicate etc

**Question**: How to get a secure and private server (python package manager) always up and running in the cloud?

Comment: You can host packages on Amazon S3 without minimal setup or no additional dependencies. I have provided instructions here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57552988/3007402

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go to Azure WebApp on Linux:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-custom-docker-image

This is roughly just a simple way to deploy a container without the burden of Kubernetes. [ACS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-service/) might be best if you really want a dedicated container solution (there is several orchestrators).

For the authentication part, htaccess file with basic authentication is supported by pip. This allow to do something like `extra-index-url = https://login:password@pypi.myserver.com/simple/`. I don't have a prefered tutorial, but google/bing something like "pip private repository" you will have no issue to find answers.

(full disclosure, I work at MS in the Azure Python SDK team)

Comment: would you still recommend the above, or are there other docs for this?

Comment: I think Azure Artifacts is able to do it now https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/

Comment: Not yet but soon actually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=vsts

Comment: @LaurentMazuel This is exactly what I was looking to do at my organization. Very excited about this!