# Private Python package repository for Azure Notebooks?

Tags: azure-sdk-python

What is the current best practice for maintaining repository of proprietary Python packages in Azure such as for use in Azure Notebooks or for building Python-based web apps?

I am hoping for MS to pick this one up to see if they have something in the works that would help integrate Python environments and package repos with Notebooks better.

Their docs only address how to install something into the main environment.
https://notebooks.azure.com/help/jupyter-notebooks/package-installation/python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to host a private python package manager in Azure or AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224788/how-to-host-a-private-python-package-manager-in-azure-or-aws)

Comment: @LaurentMazuel, revised.