# Accessing python package from custom pypi s3 server in MWAA

Tags: amazon-s3, mwaa

Our team is looking to install a custom package we set up internally using a custom pypi server on s3 like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022867/if-we-want-use-s3-to-host-python-packages-how-can-we-tell-pip-where-to-find-the). We then want to add it to a MWAA requirments.txt file. We configured the IAM policy for MWAA with full bucket access and bucket policy so that MWAA could access the static website to install the whl file. I also tested this locally with the MWAA docker container provided for testing. This worked correctly.

The issue comes when trying to try this on MWAA. I updated the requirments.txt with
--extra-index-url [www.s3-webite.com](http://www.s3-webite.com)
--trustedhost s3-url
python-package-example==1.56

For some reason this breaks all the dags. When I check cloudwatch, the requirements log shows everything except for python-package-example is installed.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-package-example===1.56 (from versions: none)

I am fairly certain it is a networking issue.
Has anyone ran into this when trying to add a custom package to your MWAA instance?
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-package-example===1.56

Example bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "Date",
    "Id": "MWAApolicyforcustomS3",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSpecificMWAAAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "mwaa-role-example"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried this on mwaa-local-runner to see if you can reproduce the error or get any useful info? This is what I use when troubleshooting Python library issues like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue I realized was that because it was a private subnet the way MWAA was installing pip packages so to fix the issue all I had to do was configure the bucket policy to allow access from the Nat gateway IP.

Answer (score 0):

who not to use [code artifact](https://aws.amazon.com/en/codeartifact/)?
I mean will be easier to manage python private and public packages

Comment: we have looked into it, but my manager has used it in the past and did not like it. So we are looking for alternatives.